# Return the First, Second and Third Earliest Purchase Dates per Purchaser

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number, partition-by

for a list of purchaser email addresses, I am trying to return one line per purchaser that has the columns '1stOrderDate', '2ndOrderDate', '3rdOrderDate' and 'TotalNumberofOrders'

I have tried using the ROW_Number function in the WHERE clause of subqueries but it reports that Windowed functions aren't allowed in the WHERE clause, so any help on how I fill in the ???s below would be gratefully received!

```
SELECT 
PT.email AS 'Email',
MIN(OT.orderdate) AS '1stOrderDate',
???               AS '2ndOrderDate',
???               AS '3rdOrderDate',
COUNT(DISTINCT OT.order_reference) AS 'TotalNumberOfOrders'    

FROM dbo.Orders AS OT
JOIN dbo.Purchaser AS PT ON OT.account_reference = PT.account_reference

GROUP BY PT.Email
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT PT.email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN OT.OrderDate END) as OrderDate_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN OT.OrderDate END) as OrderDate_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN OT.OrderDate END) as OrderDate_3,
       COUNT(DISTINCT OT.order_reference) AS TotalNumberOfOrders   
FROM (SELECT o.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_reference ORDER BY o.orderdate) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.Orders o
     ) OT JOIN
     dbo.Purchaser PT
     ON OT.account_reference = PT.account_reference
GROUP BY PT.Email
```

A couple of notes:

- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Instead, choose column names that do not require escaping.
- For the `segnum = 1` logic, you can use `MIN()`, but I think consistency is a benefit here.

EDIT:

My guess is that the problem is the difference between a `account_reference` and `email`.  Try this:

```
SELECT email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN OT.OrderDate END) as OrderDate_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN OT.OrderDate END) as OrderDate_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN OT.OrderDate END) as OrderDate_3,
       COUNT(DISTINCT OT.order_reference) AS TotalNumberOfOrders   
FROM (SELECT o.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pt.email ORDER BY o.orderdate) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.Orders o JOIN
           dbo.Purchaser PT
           ON OT.account_reference = PT.account_reference
     ) OT 
GROUP BY PT.Email
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, but just noticed some of the order 2 and order 3 dates aren't pulling through even when TotalNumberOfOrders >1, any ideas?

Comment: If you have multiple orders on the same date, they will be treated as different dates.  The `row_number()` counts orders, not dates.  You could try `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: There can potentially be multiple orders on the same date and that is fine to report the same date for the second or third dates as applicable. Dense_Rank appears to have the same problem with some pulling through as NULLs

Comment: @J-BAC . . . The `row_number()` is what you need.  Perhaps this happens when some customers have fewer than three orders.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it...I have sorted by descending TotalNumberOfOrders and the top customer with >60 orders only has a first date of purchase, the second and third dates are pulling through as NULL